# Fixing broken commits all-on-all if contributor had autocrlf = true for Git

Tags: git

I got branch with broken commits all-on-all due to Git CR auto-removal even if only one line was changed.

Our repository itself is broken: it was converted from SVN without stripping CR.

So any Git client without `autocrlf = input` fixes CR/LF ending automatically.

I fixed broken commit with monstrous series, like (with `core.autocrlf=false` and adding/removing last line to file to make them differ):

```
git co broken
git co -b fixed HASH_OF_BROKEN
git -c core.autocrlf=false reset --hard

for f in broken.txt; do echo >>$f; unix2dos $f; done

git -c core.autocrlf=false add -u
git -c core.autocrlf=false ci --amend --no-edit

for f in broken.txt; do sed -i '$ d' $f; done

git -c core.autocrlf=false add -u
git -c core.autocrlf=false ci --amend --no-edit

git cherry-pick HASH_OF_NEXT_TO_BROKEN..broken
git push origin fixed
```

Is there easy way to fix result of:

```
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in ...
```

Comment: Let me see if I understand. You have a repository that has mixed linefeeds and you want to change it to `CRLF`?

Comment: @Schwern I only need to keep legacy files with CR/LF so `git blame` will show preceding 3 year history. New files get LF internally. `autocrlf = input` does job until newcomer pushed set some messy stuff. I want to undo Git CR/LF correction.

Comment: You can use `git blame -w` to look past trivial whitespace changes, so go ahead and fix everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the goal is to have a repository with consistent line endings, it's best to rewrite the entire history using [`git-filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) than dealing with it commit-by-commit. Let's say you want consistent DOS line endings.

Write a little program that can convert the line endings of all files in a directory tree, except `.git`. If you have binary files you'll also have to skip them. Here's a simple example.

```
$ cat ~/bin/all2dos
#!/bin/sh

find . -path ./.git -prune -o -type f -print0 | xargs -0 unix2dos
```

Then use that in a `tree-filter` to convert the line endings of every commit through all history.

```
$ git filter-branch --tree-filter 'all2dos' -- --all
```

While rewriting history is scary, it is entirely reversible for a period of time. Git doesn't rewrite commits, it writes new ones and uses them. Your original commits are accessible via the [reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) and you can move your branches back to them.

```
$ git reflog
10eed67 (HEAD -> master) HEAD@{0}: filter-branch: rewrite
e8615e3 HEAD@{1}: commit (initial): Test files
```

That says the original commit for `master` was `e8615e3` and the new rewritten one is `10eed67`. I can move `master` back to the original with `git reset --hard e8615e3`.

This will result in new commit IDs, so anyone currently working on your project will have to do a `git pull --rebase=preserve` to update (which they should be doing anyway) possibly with `--ignore-cr-at-eol` to avoid conflicts because of the newline change. If they have any open branches they'll be on the old `master`; they should `git rebase master` to base them off the newly rewritten `master` branch.

Comment: `git pull --force` generally does not make sense: it passes `--force` to `git fetch` but `git fetch` is normally fetching from `refs/heads/*` to `refs/remotes/origin/*` with force update for each reference anyway.

Comment: @torek You're right, the proper thing is `git pull --rebase=preserve`. Thanks.